# Working independently where you should work collaboratively

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What phrase or word is used to describe someone, specifically in a vocational context,  who is making decisions without first discussing it with a superior or other members of the team?

Comment: I'm guessing that any term you pick would carry a lot of baggage based on the management style de jour at your company.

Comment: A mushroom grower? ... as in, keeps 'em in the dark and feeds 'em s***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they make decisions by themselves without discussing with a superior first, they are unprofessional to say the least. If, however, they ignore only their mates, they can be said to be "lone wolves" or "individualists".

> - [**"lone wolf"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lone%20wolf) - a person who prefers to work, act, or live alone.
> - [**"individualist"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/individualist) - one that pursues a markedly independent course in thought or action, one that advocates or practices individualism.